# INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE..... with two key fields

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has three fields

field_one
field_two
field_three

I'd like to do an insert/update, but instead of checking if one of the key fields already exists, I need to check if (field_one,field_two) combination is already in the database, if so, then update instead of inserting.

Comment: And what is the impediment? You just wrote in the question title what you need to use.

Comment: @Alin Purcaru: Alas, knowledge of indexes over multiple columns is still somewhat uncommon (I know I went "you can do THAT?!" when I was shown).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Create unique index your_index_name on yourtable (field_one,field_two)` ([see docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)) and use [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

MySQL will do the rest automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to do this. Easiest is probably something like this:

- Obtain the existing fields

  Insert all your fields that are not in the existing fields

  Update the rest

Answer (score 0):

Sound to me like you can use `REPLACE INTO` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` as long as there is a unique constraint on the two fields.

MySql doesn't support the MERGE statement, so need either a unique constraint or some external code.

Comment: Caveat: on duplicate, REPLACE behaves like DELETE+INSERT, whereas INSERT ... UPDATE behaves like UPDATE (important for triggers, autoincrementing fields and default values)